# Add a one day to datetime field in mysql table

Tags: mysql, datetime

I need to update and add one day all dates currently I have in the bse data, the table is carts and it ocurred only for rows with choi_id = 1030;

**CARTS**
- id
- name
- choi_id;
- inserted

I tried for:

```
UPDATE carts SET inserted = inserted + 1 where choi_id = 1030;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
UPDATE carts
   SET `inserted` = DATE_ADD(`inserted` , INTERVAL 1 DAY)
WHERE `choi_id` = 1030;
```

The DATE_ADD MySQL function adds a specified time interval to a date, seconds, minutes, months, years, etc... Your input is a datetime field, not a integer then +1 not working for that.

See here the doc: [DATE_ADD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: your field is a date type, not a number.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so

```
UPDATE carts
 SET inserted = inserted +  INTERVAL 1 DAY
 where choi_id = 1030;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE carts
   SET `inserted` = DATE_ADD(`inserted` , INTERVAL 1 DAY)
WHERE `choi_id` = 1030;
```

This works. MySQL data types exist, you can not treat a datetime as a number.